# E-Mail Viewer application

Tags: c#, java, android, email, email-client

I am trying to write an e-mail viewer application (only for receiving emails not for sending) for my project. I have searched lot many places but all are for only sending.

Can somebody guide me in right direction from where I can start. Language is not a matter for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what server you are connecting to to receive E-Mails from: POP3, IMAP or even Exchange.

- POP3 is specified in [RFC1939](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt)
- IMAP 4rev1 is specified in [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)

Also, when searching the web for "POP3" or "IMAP" you'll find loads of guides and tutorials for most languages out there.

Here some examples and/or libraries for C#:

- [OpenPOP.NET (recommended for POP3)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx
- http://dotnetctrlext.sourceforge.net/
- [Guide how to connect to a POP3 server via Telnet](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial172_Connecting-to-a-POP3-server-using-Csharp.html)
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4071/how-to-pop3-in-c/

Comment: I don't think the OP's question is at that level. He'll be using a high level API in the language of his choice (i.e. Java, C#) and won't need to know the POP3 or IMAP specification in details. He will need to concentrate on how to use such API. The links you posted would have been useful if he were to write a mail server from scratch!

Comment: I disagree to an extend - whilst the OP certainly wont need to know the protocols by heart, it is very useful to know the basics. In my own experience the RFC's are a very useful resource if you dont just want to cut and paste some code but want to understand what you are doing - and the mentioned RFC's are very clear and comparably concise. This is in fact how I started writing my own E-Mail client years ago and for me it worked great. Plus, the OP now knows what to search the web for. POP3 and IMAP. So from my point of view I cant see how this is a bad advice.

Comment: @Sascha Hennig: Absolutely you are right. I don't want any cut and paste solution. As I am making this project, I will also need to now how it is working behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of them out there!
A quick search throws many results, such as [Pooka](http://www.suberic.net/pooka/) for which the source code is available so you can look at how they have done it, learn from it, and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

here are the few good articles I have found on code project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/pop3client.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/popapp.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx

Hope this helps to somebody else!